# Display data from two table in listgrid

Tags: java, jquery, listgrid

I want show data from two table in a single listgrid.

Is it possibile?

EDIT: are two istance of two different table.

Comment: Can i have a piece of code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
addData(Record newRecord)
```

Perform a DataSource "add" operation to add new records to this component's DataSource.

This is a method to add more data in a listgrid.

There are two more variants available look this link : http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/grid/ListGrid.html

Comment: But if I understand, the problem is: "How get all data from two diffent table?" So how can you pass an array with two diffent types of object to jqgrid??

Comment: @Teo A tabular representation is to same type of things (Structure wise). We can also represent structure wise not same things, but we need to specify what are the field headers; in that case the data should be inserted manually from both the tables. I don't know listgrid supports those options or not. But we can achieve it in datatables.

Answer (score 0):

Better you can add the data from second table manually using listgrid.add API or something similar to that.

Answer (score 0):

the best method would be to

```
listgrid.addData(Record record)
```

This would help you add a new record to the DataSource. This would have an easy extraction as well. Still if possible please share some code snippet that might be more useful for an appropriate answer.